# How can I call a JavaScript function by OnClick on server side?

Tags: asp.net

I am using an `OnclientClick` function to use JavaScript function. But I couldn't call any JavaScript function by `OnClick` in server side. How to use `Onclick` for JavaScript function?

my button code

```
<asp:Button ID="registerbutton" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClientClick=" return someFunction1();"/>
```

my script

```
function someFunction1() 
{
     document.getElementById('iframestyle').src = "register.aspx";
     return false;
}
```

Comment: You need to understand the difference between the client and the server.

Answer (score 0):

For server side you need to use the OnClick attribute

```
<asp:Button ID="registerbutton" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="ServerSideFunction;"/>

protected void ServerSideFunction(EventArgs e, object sender)
{
}
```

JavsScript can not be executed on the server.

If you want to trigger server side functionality through javascript you have to use Ajax.